# Prolog instantiating variable to a list

Tags: prolog

If I have a database such as:

```
number(0).
number(1).
number(2).
number(3).
number(4).
number(5).
number(6).
number(7).
number(8).
number(9).
```

and want to write a predicate **numbers(L)** that instantiates that L to a list of numbers. i.e.

```
numbers([A,B]).
```

should instantiate A and B to 10*10 different combinations of numbers, how would I do this. I want to show the recursion in the **numbers(L)** predicate, not use maplist.

Many thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not use `number/1` for your purposes, because it is a name of a built-in predicate. Rename `number` to `num` or some other name.

A rule that produces a pair of numbers is trivial:

```
numbers([A,B]) :- num(A), num(B).
```

Yes, that was really it!

Now you can print all of the combinations like this:

```
:- numbers([A,B]), write(A), write('-'), write(B), nl, fail.
```

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/ORoFsO)

Comment: thank you - this is very helpful. I have another question (apologies I am very new to Prolog) Is there a way to do it with the one variable L, i.e. a predicate digits(L) that would instantiate L to the list of digits?  Thank you again.

Comment: @user3666362 You can do it with the existing `numbers` predicate, and `findall/3`, like this: `number_pairs(L) :- findall(I,numbers(I), L).` [Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/m9ecgI).